# Override HStack alignment for one child

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to dynamically override the alignment property of an `HStack` in an individual element?

**Consider this scenario**

1. There is a parent `HStack` with `alignment = bottom`
2. There are 3 elements inside the `HStack` of different sizes
3. I want the 3rd element to align to the top of the `HStack`. This alignment is different from the `Hstack`'s bottom alignment

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.yellow)
            .frame(height: 100)

        Rectangle()
            .fill(.blue)
            .frame(height: 20)

        // I want this to go to the top of the HStack
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.green)
            .frame(height: 50)
    }
    .background {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the `HStack` to respect the highest height of 100 and just alter the last element's alignment.

I've tried wrapping the 3rd element in another stack but that only works if I specify a `maxHeight` equal to the tallest height among the parent's children, 100.
This means these rectangles have to know about their sibling elements.

```
HStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.green)
        .frame(height: 50)
}
.frame(maxHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
```

Comment: You could wrap the last element in a VStack and put a Spacer below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
 var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.yellow)
            .frame(height: 100)
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.blue)
            .frame(height: 20)
        
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.green)
                .frame(height: 50)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .background {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

If, for some reason, you want to limit the range of how much space can the `Spacer` take up, you can add a modifier as per following example:

```
VStack {
   Rectangle()
     .fill(.green)
     .frame(height: 50)
   Spacer()
     .frame(minHeight: 10, maxHeight: 50)
}
```